# Run exports.someFunction assignment from a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have set a route in Express looking like this:

```
app.get('/api/:type/:id', api.getItemById);
```

The function api.getItemById is inside api module in routes. But inside api module I have to run a function that connects to database, and then defines all responder functions like this:

```
couchbase.connect(dbConfiguration, function (err, bucket) {
  if (err) {
    throw (err)
  }

  exports.getItemById = function (req, res) {
    if (req.params.type == 'tag' || req.params.type == 'user' || req.params.type == 'asset' || req.params.type == 'expense' || req.params.type == 'income') {
      get(req, res, req.params.type);
    } else {
      res.send(400);
    }
  };
```

});

The problem is that in this case the application doesn't find getItemById function and throws this:

```
.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
```

I am not sure I do it properly. Could you please advise how I can make that function visible to the node app if defined inside a callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: you can't. `require` is synchronous and expects that `[module.]exports` is set synchronously (at the moment the module is loaded).

You could use a module-scoped variable which is initially `false`, and is set to `true` once 
your database is set up. Your route handler could check for that:

```
var ready = false;

// connect to database
couchbase.connect(dbConfiguration, function (err, bucket) {
  if (err) {
    throw (err)
  }
  ready = true;
};

// export your route handler
exports.getItemById = function (req, res) {
  // check for readiness
  if (! ready)
    return res.send(500); // 'Internal Server Error', or any error you like

  // if ready, perform the regular action
  if (req.params.type == 'tag' || req.params.type == 'user' || req.params.type == 'asset' || req.params.type == 'expense' || req.params.type == 'income') {
    get(req, res, req.params.type);
  } else {
    res.send(400);
  }
};
```

If you don't want a setup like this (where requests can get handled before the database is connected to), you need to postpone the startup of your server (`app.listen(...)` or equivalent) until all asynchronous startup actions are done. That would require a bit more effort though.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot not export `getItemById`; you should export an initialization function that passes the function in a callback whenever the database is set up:

```
exports.init = function(callback) {
    couchbase.connect(dbConfiguration, function (err, bucket) {
      if (err) {
        throw (err)
      }

      var getItemById = function (req, res) {
        if (req.params.type == 'tag' || req.params.type == 'user' || req.params.type == 'asset' || req.params.type == 'expense' || req.params.type == 'income') {
          get(req, res, req.params.type);
        } else {
          res.send(400);
        }
      };

      callback(getItemById);
    });
}
```

And then perform your `require` like so:

```
require("api").init(function(getItemById) {
    // set up express...

   app.get('/api/:type/:id', getItemById);

   // ...
});
```